# Format \ref output from enumeration item to not include section name

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, enumerate

I'm referencing items in an enumerated list from another document (requirements.tex). I can do that, but I get extraneous information I haven't been able to remove.

Requirements.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}

\section{Engineering Requirements}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item The system shall turn trees into money. \label{Req:treesToMoney}
    \item The system must be able to process five trees per second. \label{Req:treeRate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

design.tex:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm ,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xr}

\externaldocument{../requirements/Requirements}

\begin{document}
Requirement \ref{Req:treesToMoney} is a functional requirement. 
\end{document}
```

The output from design.tex is something like:

> Requirement 1Engineering RequirementsItem.1 is a functional requirement.

This output looks awful. Not only do I get the extraneous section name and Item.#, that information isn't separated by spaces.

Is there a way to format the output of \ref? Possibly to exclude the extraneous information but at-least to separate the different pieces of information by spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `xr` was written long before `hyperref`. This package changes the way labels are stored in the `.aux` file, so `xr` finds improper values and does the best it can.

If you use `hyperref` in the `Requirements.tex` file, then you should use it also in `design.tex` and use `xr-hyper` instead of `xr`.

If you really don't want to use `hyperref` in `design.tex`, you can modify the workings of `xr` so that the correct `\newlabel` is called. Example of `design.tex` with a modified internal macro of `xr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr}
\makeatletter
\long\def\XR@test#1#2#3#4\XR@{%
  \ifx#1\newlabel
    \mod@newlabel{\XR@prefix#2}#3{}{}\@nil% changed line
  \else\ifx#1\@input
     \edef\XR@list{\XR@list#2\relax}%
  \fi\fi
  \ifeof\@inputcheck\expandafter\XR@aux
  \else\expandafter\XR@read\fi}
% new macro
\def\mod@newlabel#1#2#3#4\@nil{\newlabel{#1}{{#2}{#3}}}
\makeatother

\externaldocument{Requirements}

\begin{document}
Requirement \ref{Req:treesToMoney} is a functional requirement.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The document `Requirements.tex` loads package `nameref` (via package `hyperref`) that changes the layout of the label data in the `.aux` file. Document `design.tex` does not use `nameref` and package `xr` does not know `nameref`. Sometimes `xr-hyper` can be used. In package `zref-xr` I have rewritten the algorithm to support label import from `zref` and LaTeX labels to `zref` and/or LaTeX labels with support for packages `nameref`/`hyperref`, `titleref`, and `ntheorem`.

Example file `design.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm ,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\zxrsetup{%
  tozreflabel=false, % not needed, since `zref` is not used otherwise
  toltxlabel=true, % classical LaTeX labels that can be referenced with \ref, \pageref
}
\zexternaldocument*{Requirements}% star form: only LaTeX labels are imported

\begin{document}
Requirement \ref{Req:treesToMoney} is a functional requirement.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]